# Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, http-headers

I'm developing a REST webservice in Node.JS to work with the backbone framework.
I've defined a Person model with urlRoot: `http://localhost:3000/users` and I've created a request handler which adds the person to a database on receiving a post request.

`app.post('/users', user.add(db));`

```
exports.add = function(db){
    return function(req,res){

        console.log(req.body);

        var name = req.body.name;
        var age = req.body.age;
        var sex = req.body.sex;
        var job = req.body.job;

        var peopleDb = db.get('people');

        peopleDb.insert({
            'name':name,
            'age':age,
            'sex':sex,
            'job':job
        },function(e,docs){
            if(e){
                console.log(e);
            }else
            {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
                res.writeHead(200);
                res.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I try to execute the code, I get this in the console:

`Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I read from other answers that adding the headers:`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,PUT,POST,DELETE` would solve the problem but it hasn't worked for me. I have also tried putting these headers in an .htaccess file but no luck.

Can someone tell me if there's something wrong with the code or any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using `express` you can use the [cors](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors/) package to allow CORS like so instead of writing your middleware;

```
var express = require('express')
, cors = require('cors')
, app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get(function(req,res){ 
  res.send('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement a response when using the same path with the `OPTIONS` HTTP method. I have this code for allowing CORS in a whole express app:

```
var app = express()
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers.origin) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Authorization')
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE')
        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') return res.send(200)
    }
    next()
})
// configure your routes
```